# Problem unpacking field 44 in unpacking JPOS ISO 8583

Tags: java, iso, iso8583, jpos

I am sending the following ISO message from client to server. I am trying to unpack this message.

```
A4M080000200F638669128B0A00800000000064000A016434184******00330
300000000000000000000000000000011407380151599213291101146011050
051000091D000000000692900132434184******0033=2707201********000
00001355008NRBGUL01NRBB                          DHAKA
                000050HEAD OFFICE                   9999
                                                 00120190114NRB
B      NRBB                         00000000000000001 050840NRB
BNRBB      1330110800680080810101001000000000000000000000000000
0007013157800000000001***
   004TC=5
```

The A4M08000 at the beginning of the message is a header that I'm not passing to the packager.

The ISO packager is defined as follows :

https://pastebin.com/DaEZrzk8

I am facing the following error:

```
org.jpos.iso.ISOException: org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR: Problem unpacking field 44 (java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException) unpacking field=44, consumed=429
    at org.jpos.iso.ISOBasePackager.unpack(ISOBasePackager.java:334)
    at org.jpos.iso.ISOMsg.unpack(ISOMsg.java:467)
    at com.era.atm.UnpackISOMessage.parseISOMessage(UnpackISOMessage.java:36)
    at com.era.socket.Processor.doProcessing(Processor.java:79)
    at com.era.socket.Processor.run(Processor.java:43)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at com.era.socket.Server.run(Server.java:64)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The code is as follows:

```
try {    

            InputStream is = UnpackISOMessage.class.getResourceAsStream("fields.xml") ;
            GenericPackager packager = new GenericPackager(is);

            ISOMsg isoMsg = new ISOMsg();
            isoMsg.setPackager(packager);
            isoMsg.unpack(message.getBytes());
            return isoMsg;
        } catch (ISOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UnpackISOMessage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Please help me how can I solve this error?

Comment: Can you share the assignment of message variable? The A4M at the beginning looks weird, it should start with the MTI 0800.

Comment: Having deleted the "A4M08000" from the beginning. I could parse the message until field 44 as in your example. There are some misalignment between what you received and your packager starting at field 44, which  comes as 00 length so it's empty which is weird, it is also weird that you define that field as LL while it is length=2. IFA_CHAR with length 25 seems more appropriate. With that modification fields 49 and 51 look good, but next 61, 102 and 103 look empty

Comment: @AndrésAlcarraz, A4M08000 is the header. It does nothing. Before parsing, I remove this header.  So should I set field 44 types to  IFA_CHAR with length 25? Then will this problem solve?

Comment: I said there are several misalignments between what you are receiving and what you are defining in your packager, I just found the problem with field 44 but there appears to be more. We cannot fully answer your question without more data.
Do you know what do you excepct in each field? i.e. what is the sender sending in each field? That would help narrow the rest misalignement problems.
Also it would be a good idea to advise in your question about the header, we a not foreseers, and you didn't add what you are setting to your message, that would have clarified the header thing.

Comment: Also is IF_CHAR, I accidentally added the A.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to unpack a binary image using a String where you call its `getBytes()` method. Beware that depending on your encoding, which probably defaults to UTF-8 binary data can be easily corrupted. Use a `byte[]` with the image instead. In addition, the dump you show there is not an hexdump, and it's probably not including unprintable characters.

Take a look at http://jpos.org/blog/2014/09/message-hex-dump/ for further info about dumps.